# Not getting $_POST data

Tags: php, ajax, post

I've never run into this situation I'm having now.  And am using this setup in another part of the site.  I cannot figure out why I don't get any post data, my session variables never update.

Here is the html form, dynamically creating a row of check boxes:

```
$html .= '<form id="status_form">';
    foreach ($leads as $key => $type) {
        $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name"' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '" class="box_status" value="1"';
        if (something = true) {
            $html .= ' checked="checked"';
        }
        $html .= ' />';
        $html .= '<label class="checkbox-inline" for"' . $key . '">' . $type . ' (' . @$count[$key] . ')</label>';
    }
    $html .= '</form>';

    echo $html;
```

Each time a checkbox is checked, javascript is submitting the form to primarily update session variables and then reload the page:

```
function update_report() {
            var form_data = $("#status_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/test.php',
                data: form_data,
                success: function() {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        }

        $('.box_status').change(function(){
            update_report();
        });
```

And here is the test.php file:

```
session_start();

if (isset ($_POST)) {

  $_SESSION['crm']['reports']['index'] = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
        $_SESSION['crm']['reports']['index'][] = $k;
    }

    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;

    echo true;
}
```

I've double checked and the form is displayed correctly, the ajax makes the call, I've done "hello world" checks in test.php.. it even goes into the `if(isset($_POST))`  portion, but the session variables don't change, and if I assign `$_POST` to another session variable, it shows me nothing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `$_POST` contains?

Comment: As I've said, I don't see anything when trying to display $_POST, most specifically, if i var_dump($_POST), i get null

Comment: `if( isset( $_POST ) )` is **always** `true`, because `$_POST` is always initialized as an empty array if there's no POST request. Try something like `if( !empty( $_POST ) )` or better yet `if( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) == 'post' )` and see if that makes a difference, because I can't see how you are trying to review the `$_SESSION` content. If you are using the same `test.php` script for that, it will continuously overwrite your previous values (with nothing).

Comment: So i've changed it to if(!empty($_POST))  and now it doesn't go into the test.php logic.  when var_dumping $_POST i get an empty array.

Comment: How are you reviewing the `var_dump()` bit? If you call the `test.php` without your AJAX code, of course `$_POST` will be empty. :-) Unless you actually make a POST request to that script in some other way.

Comment: Debugging what that contains can also mean to have a look at the browser's network console while the request is fired

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, that's a very valid point, of course. I forgot about that, just now.

Comment: The primary way I was attempting was through assigning `$_POST` to a session variable in test.php and I've also tried echoing `$_POST` back from test.php.  Issue is, `$_POST` is empty.  That's especially apparent to me now that I'm testing for `!empty($_POST)` and it's not passing that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your string concatenation:

```
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name"' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '" class="box_status" value="1"';
```

`name"'` is supposed to be `name="'` You forgot the equal sign. jQuery serialize only takes input tags with names.

Your solution:

```
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '" class="box_status" value="1"';
```

**Note:**
The best way to debug this sort of problem is to take a look at your generated html. When you load the page, check the page source. You also made the same error on your label tag.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered this myself.  I attempted to analyze the generated html and even compared to the other working part of the website, but I read right past it who knows how many times.